# Rake unconsistent behaviour between dev and test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rake, rake-task

I develop a RoR application using a PostgreSQL database, based on this database.yml definition:

```
    # PostGre databases

    default: &default
      host : localhost
      adapter: postgresql
      encoding: unicode
      pool: 5
      username: keyman
      password: keymanApp
      schema_search_path: "keyman"

    development:
      <<: *default
      database: keyman_dev

    test:
      <<: *default
      database: keyman_test
```

I created a small Rake routine, so I can easily drop and create my postgreSQL database, including the schema I work with:

```
        namespace :db do
            desc 'Create database schemas before going for the first migration'
            task init: ['db:drop','db:create'] do
            ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("CREATE SCHEMA keyman AUTHORIZATION keyman")
            puts 'Database initialised'
            end
          end
```

When I run rake db:init, it is executed both on dev and test environments:

```
$ rake db:init
Dropped database 'keyman_dev'
Dropped database 'keyman_test'
Created database 'keyman_dev'
Created database 'keyman_test'
Database initialised
```

But the result is not the same: the  schema 'keyman' is created for the keyman_dev database, but not for the keyman_test database.

I need to run explicitly rake db:init RAILS_ENV=test to get the schema created on the test database.

It sounds strange to me! Do you have an explanation?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

when running `bin/rake -T db` we can see the following descriptions for `db:create` and `db:drop`

```
rake db:create              # Creates the database from DATABASE_URL or config/database.yml for the current RAILS_ENV (use db:create:all to create all databases in the config). Without RAILS_ENV or when RAILS_ENV is development, it defaults to creating the development and test databases
rake db:drop                # Drops the database from DATABASE_URL or config/database.yml for the current RAILS_ENV (use db:drop:all to drop all databases in the config). Without RAILS_ENV or when RAILS_ENV is development, it defaults to dropping the development and test databases
```

So, when you run those tasks in the development environment, they both do the `development` and `test` databases, but that doesn't mean that other tasks (such as your custom task) automatically run in both environments, you're task is still only running in the `development` environment.

Something like this in your rake task *should* get that query to run in both tables, though this is untested.

```
environments = Rails.env.development? ? [:development, :test] : [Rails.env.to_sym]

environments.each do |env|
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(env)
  # do something
end
```

Comment: Thank you for this very clear explanation, I'll pay attention to this in my future rake tasks.